# Replace a string by an empty line in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, string

I can't seem to find a solution to this problem with Notepad++. I have a text file with many `\EC` strings on a single line and I have to get rid of them. In other words, I want to automatically replace the `\EC` strings by `nothing`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find: **`.*\\EC.*\r?\n`**

Replace with: *(nothing)*

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I did not express the problem properly. The result should not be a blank line, but it should be "no line". That is, I want to replace `\EC` by nothing.

Comment: @pluton Do you want to remove all the lines that contains `\EC`? If yes, must replace it with *nothing*.

Comment: But I do not know how to achieve this "nothing". I always get an blank line instead?

Comment: @pluton `Nothing` means no content for `replace with` (not even a space).